# How can I get to the work directory of another recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to create an own recipe in which I need both a binary from the U-Boot sources and a binary from the Kernel sources.

Can I get the paths to those sources ([`S`variable](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-S)) in my own recipe on a save way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

You can take the binaries from `${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}` though, if your recipe depends the deploy task from the respective recipe. That dependency is created by:

```
 do_configure[depends] = "u-boot:do_deploy"
```

If your recipe include the line above, that means that u-boot will be put into the `DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE` before the `do_configure` task from your recipe is being run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I need mkimage in my own recipe. Should I create an append file for u-boot and deploy mkimage as well as the u-boot binary itself?

Comment: Well, `mkimage` should be in your sysroot `${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}/usr/bin`. Thus, `mkimage` should be in the path, as long as your recipe has `DEPENDS += "u-boot-mkimage-native"` in it.

Comment: Ahh okay, thats what I have searched, thank you very much